# Enabling the ability to slide images

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I currently have an app that displays an image.  You have to press a button to move the image forward or backward in the set.  I am only using the UIImageView controller and and am just populating it with the next image in the set.

I would like to make it so that the users can just slide the images.  I know there are some pre-built controllers to do this but would like to do it without re-writing the entire app.

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Look into Session 104 - Designing Apps with Scrollviews of the 2010 WWDC (you can get the videos for free from the Apple Developer page). It covers the exact same situation in every aspect and no answer of whatsoever length here could cover it so well.

Seriously, watch it!

Comment: Yes, this video is what u need

Answer (score 1):

Use a UIScrollView with UIImageView(s) on it and set the scroll views pagingEnabled = YES. There are tons of tutorials out there that explain this and the WWDC videos from 2009 and 2010 include two very nice sample applications on the subject as well.

A good point to start is the "scrolling" sample code by Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 0):

By sliding the image, do you mean swiping it left or right to iterate through a list of them? Like is done in the iPhone's image viewer? You can embed UIImageViews into a scroll view to get that kind of action.

Answer (score 0):

Check out apple's "PhotoScroller" app in the example code.  It should give you everything you need.  You may be looking at a significant restructuring of viewController though.